# Error while using If else

Tags: dev-c++

I'm trying to create a program that you need to enter 3 numbers and needs to tell you which one is greater, and I'm getting the error:[Error] expected '(' before 'else'.
The error is in line 17 and 21. 
Here is the code.

```
using namespace std;


int main(){

  int n1, n2, n3;

  cout<<"Type 3 numbers : ";
  cin>>n1>>n2>>n3;

  if (n1 > n2 && n1 > n3){
    cout<<"The graeter is : "<<n1;
  } 
  if else{
    (n2 > n3);
    cout<<"The graeter is: "<<n2;
  }
  if else {
    cout<<"The graeter is: "<<n3;
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put `if else` where it should be `else if`. You also put the condition inside the code block. In your final test, you only `else` because there is no other alternative beyond this. Try this:

```
int main()
{ 
  int n1, n2, n3;

  cout<<"Type 3 numbers : ";
  cin>>n1>>n2>>n3;

  if (n1 > n2 && n1 > n3) {
    cout<<"The greater is : "<<n1;
  }
  else if (n2 > n3) {
    cout<<"The greater is: "<<n2;
  }
  else {
    cout<<"The greater is: "<<n3;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I can't run it at the moment, so there may be other errors I haven't spotted.

Some programmers recommend putting brackets in to ensure your intention is explicit (see the [Dangling Else Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else)) but in this case it isn't necessary.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Please accept the answer and up-vote it!